# How to make page like Appstore in iOS 11

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, uinavigationbar, ios11

I'm working on my own app in which I want to build a page almost like Appstore page. I googled and found solution for [Large text](https://github.com/tzahola/iOS-11-Large-Title-Navigation-Bar) but not able to find for image on navigation bar as shown in attached screenshots with this.
[image] 
[image]

Is anybody done this kinda work, need help and suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

`image on navigation bar`: you can use `navigationItem.titleView` add a `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import UIKit 
class HomeViewController: UIViewController { 

   override func viewDidLoad() { 
      super.viewDidLoad() 

      let logo = UIImage(named: "logo")
      let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
      imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
      self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView

   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one line:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView.init(image: UIImage.init(named: yourImageName))
```